# Python - API multiple responses

Tags: python-3.x, api

I am currently working on obtaining data from a nested JSON response called "Result"
Now after reviewing the API documentation, they say that they only return 100 records per request, so which means if we have 425 records I would have to pass the request. get at least 4 times with:

- /example
- /example?$skip=100
- /example?$skip=200
- /example?$skip=400

After that is done it should write the response list in a csv file.I have parsed the response from the get to json.loads, I have converted the dictionary to list and created a for loop that writes whatever is in the "Result" dictionary.

My question is how can I create that it loops also the request.get and increments the url value to skip 100,200,300,400. Hope this makes sense

Comment: Take a look at [JSON API](https://jsonapi.org/format/1.1/) specification.  That should help you understand the concept of pagination.

Comment: I have reviewed that but it doesn't suit me in that case for paging...

Answer (score 0):

So after searching and searching the best way that worked for me was.

1. Creating a for loop with the number of times that it needs to loop over.
2. toSkip = (i+1) * 100
3. Concatenate the string with 'url string' + '?$Skip=' + str(toSkip)
4. Create a request with passing the authorization header
5. Parse it with json.loads
6. Write the result to a csv file or google sheets API